# Router en Proxmox con dos tarjetas de red

Tags: servidor, red, proxmox, lan

Quiero tener un router dentro de mi Proxmox que reciba internet de otro router pero el que se encuentra dentro del Proxmox filtre los paquetes dentro de las demás máquinas virtuales.

### Escenario

Tengo un servidor Proxmox que se conecta a internet a través de un router secundario (repetidor), y este servidor tiene una tarjeta de red dedicada y otra integrada en la placa base (la que todo PC tiene).

### Problema

No puedo sustituir el Proxmox para que enrute toda la red local de mi casa porque me mataría mi familia xd, así que solo debo proteger la red secundaria que habría en mi cuarto.

### Pregunta

¿Es posible usar una máquina virtual de Proxmox que contenga un OPNsense y actue como router? El objetivo es tener un router con software como OPNsense o Pfsense filtrando la red interna del Proxmox.

PD: si me pueden indicar los pasos que tendría que seguir se lo agradecería.